# Can I influence the positioning of bubble labels in an Anychart Bubble chart?

Tags: anychart

I have an AnyChart Bubble chart where each bubble has a label.
When I set the position of the label to Outside the label is positioned above the label. Result is that labels are overlapping other bubbles and/or labels.
[image: See here for an example.]

Is it possible to 'search' for a place to position the label so that it does not overlay another bubble or label?

Comment: We would like to assist you. 
Please recreate your chart in our Playground environment to do so. 
https://playground.anychart.com/

We are requesting this so we can provide you with a precise solution.

Comment: I have recreated it in https://playground.anychart.com/Ljurqmpv/1
The JSON I use is generated in C# code